# Одного ли корня слова?

Tags: этимология

Однокоренные ли данные слова: *запах, пахнет, запахнуть, пах, пахарь*?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Поправил, т. к. вопрос имел вид не подлежащей рассмотрению и осмыслению фразы.

Comment: Поправил. Как и ответы, вопросы не следует превращать в личные письма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В современном языке можно выделить 4 группы однокоренных слов:1) ЗапАхнуть, пахнет, зАпах; 2) запахнУть, запАх; 3) пах; 4) пахарь.

Исторически две первые группы родственны между собой, "пАхнуть" происходит от "пахнУть", от пахъ - дуновение, движение воздуха, а также действие, вызывающее дуновение, где "па" - звукоподражательное (сравнить: пыхтеть);

у "пахать" неясное происхождение, разные версии;

пах - от паз (pas) - стык, соединение, связь, потом щель на месте соединения (из словаря Шанского).

Comment: Благодарю! Ваш ответ более менее удовлетворяет мой вопрос. Незначительные вопросы остались, но это оставлю для самостоятельной "археологии". )))

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд - нет. Здесь как минимум четыре группы основ, звучащих и пишущихся одинаково на данный исторический момент. 
ЗАпах пАхнул пахУче. ПАхарь пахАл пАжить по весновспАшке. Пах в пахУ пАховой грыжи. ЗапАх пахнУв запахнУлся. Возможно, я учёл не всё. Но где-то в глубине истории, некоторые корни могли родиться от одного понятия.

P.S. Чуть не забыл Пахома. :) Но с ним проще, чем со всем остальным. Это греческий Παχώμιος.

Comment: В том-то всё и дело, что интересно родство этих слов.

Comment: Родство этих слов, скорее всего, надо искать в далёкой истории русского языка. А возможно и не русского. Вот, что пишет по этому поводу Википедия -   [ссылка](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85) Но это лишь предположения. С этим можно соглашаться, можно не соглашаться. Я вот абсолютно убеждён, что слово "поляна", "поле" первично происходит от слова "паль". И древнеславянское племя "поляне", правильно должно произноситься именно "пАляне". По их основной специализации - подсечно-огневому земледелию. Но доказать это, практически невозможно. Можно лишь предполагать.